# Ассинхронные функции js

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Почему "j" выводится,после того как функция qwe отработает?
По идее же первая функция берёт обещание от qwe() что та вернёт колбек и род функция должна сразу же вывести j а потом i когда qwe отработает, но работает наоборот?

```js
async function change() {

  qwe();
  console.log('j');

}
async function qwe() {
  let i = 10000000;
  while (i > -2) {
    i--;
    if (i == 0) {
      console.log('i');
    }
  }
  return true;
}

change();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

код внутри async функции выполняется синхронно до первого `await`

```js
async function change() {

  qwe();
  console.log('j');

}
async function qwe() {
  let i = 10000000;
  await Promise.resolve();
  while (i > -2) {
    i--;
    if (i == 0) {
      console.log('i');
    }
  }
  return true;
}

change();
console.log('k');
```